# getting nullable object on json unmarshal in golang

Tags: json, parsing, go, struct

> Go code(jsonTestParse.go)
>
> (this is just a test example I made, please don't argue that I should
> use list of students in cls struct)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
)

type student struct {
    ID       string `json:"id"`
    Name     string `json:"name"`
    Standard string `json:"std"`
}

type cls struct {
    st student `json:"cls"`
}

func getValues() (cls, error) {
    var clss cls
    dataBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("studentclass.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("File error: %v\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    err = json.Unmarshal(dataBytes, &clss)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Errorf("%s", err)
    }
    return clss, err
}

func main() {
    s, err := getValues()
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", s)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

> Json File (studentclass.json)

```
{
    "cls": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test",
        "std": "0"
    }
}
```

When I run this code with `go run jsonTestParse.go` it gives me this output:

```
main.cls{st:main.student{ID:"", Name:"", Standard:""}}
<nil>
```

Please help me why I'm getting this blank object

```
main.cls{st:main.student{ID:"", Name:"", Standard:""}}
```

instead of this

```
main.cls{st:main.student{ID:"1", Name:"test", Standard:"0"}}
```

Plus It would be great to help on how to get these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because your **cls** struct has embedded private struct (lower case unexported field) of **student** `st`, change to exported field should work, that is:

```
type cls struct {
    // St field will be unmarshalled
    St student `json:"cls"`
}
```

See in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-IFQSrLf3Z)

Comment: @rsudip90, glad it helps, you can actually read this from Go API docs [here](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal), especially this line: `Unmarshal will only set exported fields of the struct.`